# Vagrant env variable to Docker build

Tags: docker, vagrant, vagrantfile, dockerfile

I'm using Vagrant and Docker to create development environments but I'm stuck with something.
I have a config.yaml file with the definition of several variables, including one which is "drush_version".

Then in my Vagrantfile, I do :

```
.....
web.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
d.build_dir = "./docker/php/#{php_version}/#{web_server}"
d.create_args = ["--env", "DRUSH_VERSION=#{drush_version}"]
.....
```

And finally in the Dockerfile which is called, I have :

```
.....
# Installation of drush
RUN git clone https://github.com/drush-ops/drush.git /usr/local/src/drush
RUN cd /usr/local/src/drush && git checkout $DRUSH_VERSION
RUN ln -s /usr/local/src/drush/drush /usr/bin/drush
RUN cd /usr/local/src/drush && composer update && composer install
.....
```

I was expecting drush to be installed with the chosen version, but unfortunately it doesn't work...
The thing is that when the container is built, the $DRUSH_VERSION variable is always empty.

But after the docker container is started, if I run "echo $DRUSH_VERSION" in the container, I can see that the variable is well defined.

If I add "ENV DRUSH_VERSION 8.0.0-rc2" at the top of my Dockerfile, it will work but I want to set it in my config.yaml file.

I think the problem is that I need to pass this variable during the "docker build", and not the "docker run" but I really don't know how to do it...

How can I pass variable from Vagrant to "docker build" ?
Can someone point me in the right direction ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately at the moment this is not doable.

There is a feature in the 1.9.0 milestone that will allow you to pass build variables into `docker build`, but this effectively gives you the same then as defining your own `ENV` variable in your `Dockerfile`.

https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/14634

For now though, you need to hard-code your version number in your `Dockerfile`.

And actually, this isn't such a bad thing as it means your build will be repeatable (i.e., won't have a dependency on anything other than your `Dockefile`).

Comment: EDIT : 1.9.0 has been released this morning, I will try the new ARG instruction : https://github.com/docker/docker/releases/tag/v1.9.0